# Prefast for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, prefast

Where can I find a download of Prefast for Visual Studio 2008?
I am not able find it through Google or the MSDN Website.

Answer (score 5):

PREfast is included in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK). Start here for instructions on how to get the WDK:

- http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx

I'm not sure how easy it is to integrate into Visual Studio.  Visual Studio 2008 includes a C/C++ analysis function (the /analyze option) which is similar in some ways to PREfast (but I'm not sure how similar - many articles seem to indicate it's the same thing).