# MSVC equivalent of __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm finding `__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))` to be very useful as a means of encouraging developers not to ignore error codes returned by functions, but I need this to work with MSVC as well as gcc and gcc-compatible compilers such as ICC. Do the Microsoft Visual Studio C/C++ compilers have an equivalent mechanism ? (I've tried wading through MSDN without any luck so far.)

Comment: Sure- it's called an exception.

Comment: @DeadMG: yes, unfortunately that's not quite as immediate as a compiler warning, and usually someone else has to fix the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `_Check_return_`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx) for examples of similar annotations and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx) for function behaviour. It's supported since MSVC 2012.

Example:

```
_Check_return_
int my_return_must_be_checked() {
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - the original question was asked back in 2010, when obviously this didn't exist in MSVC, but it's good to know that it's now been added. I guess one can implement a macro which checks `_MSCVER` first and then uses `_Check_return_` if it's supported.

Comment: I've now made this the accepted answer, as it is more up-to-date than the earlier answers. I've also added an answer of my own which includes a cross-platform macro with checks for MSVC version etc. Thanks again!

Comment: There's also [`_Must_inspect_result_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Note that this will not be caught during compiling normally. You must execute SAL static code analysis to get a warning for this.

Answer (score 13):

#### UPDATE FOR MSVC 2012 AND LATER

*Many thanks to @Albert for pointing out that MSVC now supports the annotation `_Check_return_` as of Visual Studio 2012 when using SAL static code analysis. I'm adding this answer so that I can include a cross-platform macro which may be useful to others:*

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ >= 4)
#define CHECK_RESULT __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1700)
#define CHECK_RESULT _Check_return_
#else
#define CHECK_RESULT
#endif
```

Note that, unlike gcc *et al*, (a) MSVC requires annotations on both declaration *and* definition of a function, and (b) the annotation needs to be at the start of the declaration/definition (gcc allows either). So usage will typically need to be e.g.:

```
// foo.h

CHECK_RETURN int my_function(void); // declaration
```

```
// foo.c

CHECK_RETURN int my_function(void)  // definition
{
    return 42;
}
```

Note also that you'll need the `/analyze` (or `-analyze`) switch if compiling from the command line, or the equivalent if using the Visual Studio IDE. This also tends to slow the build down somewhat.

Answer (score 5):

Some editions of VisualStudio come packaged with a static analysis tool that used to be called [PREFast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016553/prefast-for-visual-studio-2008) (Now called simply "Code Analysis for C/C++").  PREFast uses annotations to mark up code.  One of those annotations, [MustCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182042.aspx), does what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks interesting - can you fix the link for MustCheck ?

Comment: @John + @Paul: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/tools/annotations.mspx <-- The first example in the docx contains the `__checkReturn` annotation ;)

Comment: 'Prefast' is now called 'Code Analysis for C/C++' - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz.aspx

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it may do the job - we use cl and makefile builds so it should be easy enough to add a prefast option when building.

Comment: @Paul R - note that this will slow down your builds a lot, and also generate a lot of warnings that you may not care about.  I would do this periodically instead of on every build, to avoid negative feedback on what's a valuable tool.

Comment: @Steve: thanks - noted - I'm not sure I'll be able to persuade everyone to install this stuff but may well make it an optional build step for those who choose to.

Comment: This is now called [_Check_return_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx) in the current Code Analysis implementation.

Comment: @bfulgham:  Thanks for the info.  I'm mostly off the VS stack these days.  Could you please edit my answer with whatever new information you could provide?  Or even supply your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, the MS compilers don't have an equivalent pragma or attribute - the only "unused" type warning you can get is for variables when you have the optimizer turned on with the appropriate warning level.

Comment: Thanks - it's somewhat ironic that the platform that needs this the most is one whose compiler does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the SAL annotation which others have mentioned is the right
answer for MSVC, but I'm guessing some people will be interested in
more portability than just MSVC, GCC, and GCC-compatible compliers,
so…

First off, GCC only supports `warn_unused_result` since 3.4. You *may*
want to check the values of `__GNUC__` / `__GNUC_MINOR__` instead of
just checking if `__GNUC__` is defined, although at this point I have
trouble imagining anyone using a version of GCC older than 3.4.

Several compilers support the GCC-style function attribute, and may or
may not define `__GNUC__` and friends:

- Clang (check with `__has_attribute(warn_unused_result)`), and
  compilers based on it (emscripten, xlc 13+, armclang, etc.), though
  AFAIK it always masquerades as at least GCC 4.2, so you probably
  don't *need* an explicit check.
- Intel doesn't always define `__GNUC__` (see the `-no-gcc` flag). I
  don't know when they started supporting it (their documentation is
  severely lacking), but I know 16.0+ is safe.
- TI 8.0+ supports it
- TI 7.3+ supports it when --gcc is passed;
  `__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__` will be defined when it is.
- Oracle Developer Studio 12.6+ supports it in C++ mode, [though not
  C](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4124723).
- PGI supports it in C++ mode. AFAICT it's undocumented so I'm not
  sure when it was added (it's #1650-D), but it's definitely present
  in 17.10+. It's silently ignored in C mode, hopefully they'll
  implement it some day.

Additionally, C++17 adds a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. For versions of
GCC/clang which support `[[nodiscard]]` in C++17 mode you can also use
`[[gnu::nodiscard]]` in C++11 and greater mode, but if you're hiding
it behind a macro anyways I don't see a reason to do so instead of
just using `__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))`.

Putting it together, there is a [HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/api-reference.html#HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT) macro in [Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/) which looks like:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >= 201703L)
#  define HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT [[nodiscard]]
#elif \
  HEDLEY_GNUC_HAS_ATTRIBUTE(warn_unused_result,3,4,0) || \
  HEDLEY_INTEL_VERSION_CHECK(16,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(8,0,0) || \
  (HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(7,3,0) && defined(__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__)) || \
  (HEDLEY_SUNPRO_VERSION_CHECK(5,15,0) && defined(__cplusplus)) || \
  HEDLEY_PGI_VERSION_CHECK(17,10,0)
#  define HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))
#elif defined(_Check_return_) /* SAL */
#  define HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT _Check_return_
#else
#  define HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT
#endif
```

You should be able to strip out the internal Hedley macros and just
copy the logic without too much trouble if you don't want to use
Hedley (it's public domain / CC0). If you choose to do so you should
probably base your port off the version in the repo as I'm far less
likely to remember to keep this answer up to date with new
information.