# Is there a good way to make sure a C++ function result is not ignored?

Tags: c++, lint

I ran into a case recently where I had a const member function performing an operation and returning a result. For example,

```
class Foo { ...
    Foo add(Foo const & x) const;
}
```

But someone else was inadvertently calling it like it was updating the `this` object (ignoring the result):

```
Foo a = ...;
Foo b = ...;
a.add(b);
```

(This bug was actually introduced by an imperfect refactoring.)

Is there a way to make the last line above trigger an error or a warning? The next best thing would be a run-time catch, which is mostly addressed by the following template. However, it kills the return value optimization, as seen by the counter result.

```
template<typename T>
class MustTake {
    T & obj;
    bool took;
public:
    MustTake(T o) : obj(o), took(false) {}
    ~MustTake() { if (!took) throw "not taken"; }
    operator T&() { took = true; return obj;}
};

struct Counter {
    int n;
    Counter() : n(0) {}
    Counter(Counter const & c) : n(c.n+1) {}
    ~Counter() {}
};

Counter zero1() {
    return Counter();
}

MustTake<Counter> zero2() {
    return Counter();
}

int main() {
    Counter c1 = zero1();
    printf("%d\n",c1.n);    // prints 0
    Counter c2 = zero2();
    printf("%d\n",c2.n);    // prints 1
    zero1();    // result ignored
    zero2();    // throws
    return 0;
}
```

I suppose I can ameliorate the inefficiency by using a macro so that MustTake<> is debug only and a no-op for release.

I am looking for a compile-time solution. Failing that, I am looking for the best run-time solution.

Comment: If you're using GCC, I think it has the `-Wunused-result` flag to enable a warning for that.

Comment: Picking a better method name would be my suggestion.  If I read `a.add(b)` I would immediately think mutator.  How about `a.newListWithHead(b)` or something similar, depending on what's actually happening?  Not as succinct as `add`, but adding isn't really what you are doing here.

Comment: I like spong's idea of changing the name.  For example, you could change it to `a + b` (if it makes sense to do so) and then everyone would know that "a + b" doesn't modify a, but they can easily write "a += b" to get the effect they wanted (I think).

Comment: @Sam and others, I'm using MSVC 2010 and GCC 3 (which I suppose will be Clang with Xcode 4).

Comment: -Wunused-result tends to spew. A user is not going to see the warning about a.add(b) amidst the spew.

Comment: @spong, yes, the poor name was the source of the problem. The refactorer replaced Bar.plus() with Foo.add() without noticing Foo.add() returned its sum and Bar.plus() didn't.

Comment: @David: But `-Wunused-result` exists, it works, it's documented, and *it's turned on by default.*

Comment: -Wunused-result only works for functions with `warn_unused_result`. There are just too many system functions, along with `new` itself, where there is no warning about dropping an absolutely essential result on the floor. This is worse than a spew. It is an half-assed implementation.

Comment: gcc has `warn_unused_result`, msvc++ has `MustCheck` : from [other stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226308/msvc-equivalent-of-attribute-warn-unused-result)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what function attributes are for ([documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) in GCC and Clang, but it's not portable to e.g. MSVC.

```
class Foo { ...
    __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
    Foo add(Foo const & x) const;
}
```

The documentation says it's used on `realloc` *for example,* but it doesn't appear on any other standard functions on my system.

You may also be interested in using the Clang static analyzer, which tracks data flow across function calls and can give you better warnings.

Comment: It's used on quite a few syscalls on my system (debian sid) - eg, `read()` and `write()`. In glibc it's `#define`d to `__wur` (this is an implementation detail of the C library, of course)

Comment: Huh, I didn't catch that with `grep` because it didn't find the definition of `__wur`.

Comment: You can "make it portable" by wrapping it inside a macro that checks if the compiler is GCC or clang. For MSVC one may use the compiler flag `/W3` to enable warnings about unused variables. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9.aspx). Although this enables it for *all* occurrences.

Comment: @rwols: Unfortunately unused variables != unused results. You can also `#define __attribute__()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You're totally right, my bad. Aaaand I didn't even [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6433557/990142).

Answer (score 7):

For Microsoft VC++, there is the `_Check_return_` annotation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Is that different from MSVC++ `MustCheck` annotation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182042(v=VS.90).aspx  Why does microsoft have the two different sets of annotations?

Answer (score 0):

If it is important that a return value not be ignored by the caller of a function, the template `dont_ignore` may be used as follows

BEFORE:

```
int add( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}
```

AFTER:

```
dont_ignore<int> add( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}
```

When the caller of the function does not use the return value, an exception is thrown. Definition of `dont_ignore`:

```
template<class T>
struct dont_ignore
{
    const T     v;
    bool        used;

    dont_ignore( const T& v )
        :  v( v ), used( false )
    {}

    ~dont_ignore()
    {
        if ( !used )
            throw std::runtime_error( "return value not used" );
    }

    operator T()
    {
        used = true;
        return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: Back reference: http://zumalifeguard.wikia.com/wiki/Code_C%2B%2B_Functions_to_Prevent_Clients_Ignoring_Return_Values