# Visual studio equivalent for __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Considering following code:

```
struct MyType{};

MyType myFunction() __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))
{
    return MyType{};
}

int main()
{
    myFunction();
    auto storMyType = myFunction();
}
```

Not storing the return value of `myFunction` is a logical error and I want to have a compilation error on all compilers. Is there any equivalent for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSVC equivalent of \_\_attribute\_\_ ((warn\_unused\_result))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226308/msvc-equivalent-of-attribute-warn-unused-result)

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, it is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation is `_Check_return_`

> Annotates a return value and states that the caller should inspect it. The checker reports an error if the function is called in a void context.

However, I believe SAL annotations are only available in the Premium and Ultimate versions of Visual Studio.

[MSDN: Annotating Function Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx)